# Fan has posted to my Facebook page wall and it's not visible

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have set up a Facebook page for a club I'm acting as webmaster for. One of the people who has "liked" the page, has posted to the wall (it's visible in my notifications) but it's not visible on the wall.

How can I approve this?

How can set posts from fans to display by default?

Comment: Are you sure that post is still there? Maybe the post is deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are on the wall of the page, click the link at the top that says "Everyone"  - this is available just below the image strip.

Comment: Thanks - I discovered this shortly after posting you are absolutely correct!  Sorry, don't currently have enough reputation to up vote the answer

Answer (score 1):

To have posts from fans displayed on the wall by default, click on **Edit Page** at the top of the page, then **Manage Permissions**, and set **Wall Tab Shows** to **All Posts**.  Although people visiting the page wall will see the post, note that only friends of the person posting (and friends of anyone liking or commenting on the post) will normally see the post in their News Feed.

[image: Manage Permissions tab]